# play audio through earpiece in flutter ( getting only through speaker )

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Play audio through earpiece in flutter , is it possible now, is there any plugin available for this use Case

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:audio_session/audio_session.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart' as ja;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final _player = ja.AudioPlayer(
    // Handle audio_session events ourselves for the purpose of this demo.
    handleInterruptions: false,
    androidApplyAudioAttributes: false,
    handleAudioSessionActivation: false,
  );

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    AudioSession.instance.then((audioSession) async {
      // This line configures the app's audio session, indicating to the OS the
      // type of audio we intend to play. Using the "speech" recipe rather than
      // "music" since we are playing a podcast.

      await audioSession.configure(AudioSessionConfiguration(
        avAudioSessionCategory: AVAudioSessionCategory.playback,
        avAudioSessionCategoryOptions:
            AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.allowBluetooth,
        avAudioSessionMode: AVAudioSessionMode.defaultMode,
        avAudioSessionRouteSharingPolicy:
            AVAudioSessionRouteSharingPolicy.independent,
        avAudioSessionSetActiveOptions: AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptions.none,
        androidAudioAttributes: const AndroidAudioAttributes(
          contentType: AndroidAudioContentType.unknown,
          flags: AndroidAudioFlags.none,
          usage: AndroidAudioUsage.media,
        ),
        androidAudioFocusGainType: AndroidAudioFocusGainType.gain,
        androidWillPauseWhenDucked: false,
      ));
      // Listen to audio interruptions and pause or duck as appropriate.
      _handleInterruptions(audioSession);
      // Use another plugin to load audio to play.
      await _player.setUrl(
          "https://s3.amazonaws.com/scifri-episodes/scifri20181123-episode.mp3");
    });
  }

  void _handleInterruptions(AudioSession audioSession) {
    // just_audio can handle interruptions for us, but we have disabled that in
    // order to demonstrate manual configuration.
    bool playInterrupted = false;
    audioSession.becomingNoisyEventStream.listen((_) {
      print('PAUSE');
      _player.pause();
    });
    _player.playingStream.listen((playing) {
      playInterrupted = false;
      if (playing) {
        audioSession.setActive(true);
      }
    });
    audioSession.interruptionEventStream.listen((event) {
      print('interruption begin: ${event.begin}');
      print('interruption type: ${event.type}');
      if (event.begin) {
        switch (event.type) {
          case AudioInterruptionType.duck:
            if (audioSession.androidAudioAttributes!.usage ==
                AndroidAudioUsage.game) {
              _player.setVolume(_player.volume / 2);
            }
            playInterrupted = false;
            break;
          case AudioInterruptionType.pause:
          case AudioInterruptionType.unknown:
            if (_player.playing) {
              _player.pause();
              playInterrupted = true;
            }
            break;
        }
      } else {
        switch (event.type) {
          case AudioInterruptionType.duck:
            _player.setVolume(min(1.0, _player.volume * 2));
            playInterrupted = false;
            break;
          case AudioInterruptionType.pause:
            if (playInterrupted) _player.play();
            playInterrupted = false;
            break;
          case AudioInterruptionType.unknown:
            playInterrupted = false;
            break;
        }
      }
    });
    audioSession.devicesChangedEventStream.listen((event) {
      print('Devices added: ${event.devicesAdded}');
      print('Devices removed: ${event.devicesRemoved}');
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('audio_session example'),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Center(
                  child: StreamBuilder<ja.PlayerState>(
                    stream: _player.playerStateStream,
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      final playerState = snapshot.data;
                      if (playerState?.processingState !=
                          ja.ProcessingState.ready) {
                        return Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          width: 64.0,
                          height: 64.0,
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        );
                      } else if (playerState?.playing == true) {
                        return IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.pause),
                          iconSize: 64.0,
                          onPressed: _player.pause,
                        );
                      } else {
                        return IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
                          iconSize: 64.0,
                          onPressed: _player.play,
                        );
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: FutureBuilder<AudioSession>(
                  future: AudioSession.instance,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    final session = snapshot.data;
                    if (session == null) return SizedBox();
                    return StreamBuilder<Set<AudioDevice>>(
                      stream: session.devicesStream,
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        final devices = snapshot.data ?? {};
                        return Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Text("Input devices",
                                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6),
                            for (var device
                                in devices.where((device) => device.isInput))
                              Text(
                                  '${device.name} (${describeEnum(device.type)})'),
                            SizedBox(height: 16),
                            Text("Output devices",
                                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6),
                            for (var device
                                in devices.where((device) => device.isOutput))
                              Text(
                                  '${device.name} (${describeEnum(device.type)})'),
                          ],
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

if you implement the above functionality already , Please mention a solution

used plugins

1. just_audio: ^0.9.24
2. audio_session: ^0.1.7

Flutter 3.0.1 • channel stable Tools • Dart 2.17.1 • DevTools 2.12.2

Comment: no , i don't ... you can vote up this question , so some one will give answers

Comment: hi Jinto, were u able to achieve that? if yes, may i know how to did it. thanks

Comment: Did you have any luck yet?

Answer (score 0):

Try with AndroidAudioAttributes as below

```
final _player = AudioPlayer();
await _player.setAndroidAudioAttributes(const AndroidAudioAttributes(
          usage: AndroidAudioUsage.voiceCommunication));
```

AndroidAudioAttributes is imported from audio_session package.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know much about the packages you used, but the native platforms support it so it should be doable. (at least on iOS, I didn't try Android yet).

For example I got it working with this [soundpool](https://pub.dev/packages/soundpool) package and using this code

```dart
    final pool = Soundpool.fromOptions(
      options: const SoundpoolOptions(
        iosOptions: SoundpoolOptionsIos(
          audioSessionCategory: AudioSessionCategory.playAndRecord,
        ),
      ),
    );
    int soundId = await rootBundle.load('assets/sounds/pudinha.mp3').then((ByteData soundData) {
      return pool.load(soundData);
    });
    await pool.play(soundId);
```